# What regex pattern matches this string?

Tags: regex, vba, regex-negation

Been scratching my head on this for hours to no avail! I need to match 3 different parts of this string, in 3 different patterns. So one regex pattern matches the first, etc.

Here is the string:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": [
{
  "marketId": "1.123485047",
  "isMarketDataDelayed": false,
  "status": "OPEN",
  "betDelay": 0,
  "bspReconciled": false,
  "complete": true,
  "inplay": false,
  "numberOfWinners": 1,
  "numberOfRunners": 3,
  "numberOfActiveRunners": 3,
  "lastMatchTime": "2016-03-18T23:21:14.211Z",
  "totalMatched": 47663.09,
  "totalAvailable": 140527.57,
  "crossMatching": true,
  "runnersVoidable": false,
  "version": 1259153627,
  "runners": [
    {
      "selectionId": 48224,
      "handicap": 0.0,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "lastPriceTraded": 1.57,
      "totalMatched": 37408.96,
      "ex": {
        "availableToBack": [
          {
            "price": 1.56,
            "size": 1344.78
          },
          {
            "price": 1.55,
            "size": 642.45
          },
          {
            "price": 1.54,
            "size": 1034.4
          }
        ],
        "availableToLay": [
          {
            "price": 1.57,
            "size": 303.34
          },
          {
            "price": 1.58,
            "size": 2368.34
          },
          {
            "price": 1.59,
            "size": 1220.99
          }
        ],
        "tradedVolume": []
      }
    },
    {
      "selectionId": 1141,
      "handicap": 0.0,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "lastPriceTraded": 7.0,
      "totalMatched": 5863.62,
      "ex": {
        "availableToBack": [
          {
            "price": 7.0,
            "size": 286.85
          },
          {
            "price": 6.8,
            "size": 552.02
          },
          {
            "price": 6.6,
            "size": 25.81
          }
        ],
        "availableToLay": [
          {
            "price": 7.2,
            "size": 36.05
          },
          {
            "price": 7.4,
            "size": 312.79
          },
          {
            "price": 7.6,
            "size": 92.63
          }
        ],
        "tradedVolume": []
      }
    },
    {
      "selectionId": 58805,
      "handicap": 0.0,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "lastPriceTraded": 4.5,
      "totalMatched": 4390.5,
      "ex": {
        "availableToBack": [
          {
            "price": 4.5,
            "size": 209.65
          },
          {
            "price": 4.4,
            "size": 692.37
          },
          {
            "price": 4.3,
            "size": 429.69
          }
        ],
        "availableToLay": [
          {
            "price": 4.6,
            "size": 279.02
          },
          {
            "price": 4.7,
            "size": 821.2
          },
          {
            "price": 4.8,
            "size": 928.88
          }
        ],
        "tradedVolume": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
],
"id": 1
}
```

I bolded the 3 parts which need extracting. (in this case they are 1.57, 7.2 and 4.6). These numbers can be integers, have 1 or 2 decimals.

Comment: See [JSON Parser in VBA](http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2014/09/json-parser-in-vba-browsing-through-net.html)

Comment: `Instr(json, """availableToLay""":[{"""price""":")` would be easier than trying to regex this.  Parsing the whole thing would make more sense though.

Answer (score 2):

One possible regex to extract 1.57, 7.2 and 4.6 would be :

```
(?:availableToLay[^\d]+)([\d.]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/vP5iH2/1

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Just seen the answer from "florentbr" and that is a much tidier answer than mine!

Do you really need RegEx? There's probably many ways of doing this, but breaking down by commas seems to hit the right data. Open up Excel, and dump your data in Cell "A1", then past this code into the VBA editor:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getYourVals()

    Dim dataStr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim marker As String

    marker = "availableToLay"
    dataStr = Split(Range("A" & 1).Value, ",")

    For i = 1 To UBound(dataStr)

        If Mid(dataStr(i), 2, Len(marker)) = marker Then

            Debug.Print Mid(dataStr(i), 28, Len(dataStr(i)) - 27)

        End If

        Range("A" & i + 1).Value = dataStr(i)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider parsing the JSON string altogether, flattening it for needed data. JSON formats can be thought of as an assembly of dictionaries and collections, two data structures VBA maintains. Below uses VBA Tools' [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) library.

Setup Steps

1. Import the .bas file in above link into a VBA module in IDE.
2. Add the VBA Reference for Microsoft Scripting Runtime

**VBA** Script *(loops through the results, runners, and ex collections)*

```
Sub JSONStringData()

    Dim jsonStr As String
    Dim element As Variant, e As Variant, n As Variant, r As Variant
    Dim x As Variant, s As Variant, pr As Variant, dat As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, num As Integer

    jsonStr = "{""jsonrpc"":""2.0"",""result"":" _
                & "[{""marketId"":""1.123485047"",""isMarketDataDelayed"":false,""status"":""OPEN""," _
                & """betDelay"":0,""bspReconciled"":false,""complete"":true,""inplay"":false," _
                & """numberOfWinners"":1,""numberOfRunners"":3,""numberOfActiveRunners"":3,""lastMatchTime"":" _
                & """2016-03-18T23:21:14.211Z"",""totalMatched"":47663.09,""totalAvailable"":140527.57,""crossMatching"":true," _
                & """runnersVoidable"":false,""version"":1259153627,""runners"":" _
                & "[{""selectionId"":48224,""handicap"":0.0,""status"":""ACTIVE"",""lastPriceTraded"":1.57," _
                & """totalMatched"":37408.96,""ex"":{""availableToBack"":[{""price"":1.56,""size"":1344.78}," _
                & "{""price"":1.55,""size"":642.45},{""price"":1.54,""size"":1034.4}],""availableToLay"":" _
                & "[{""price"":1.57,""size"":303.34},{""price"":1.58,""size"":2368.34},{""price"":1.59,""size"":1220.99}]," _
                & """tradedVolume"":[]}},{""selectionId"":1141,""handicap"":0.0,""status"":""ACTIVE""," _
                & """lastPriceTraded"":7.0,""totalMatched"":5863.62,""ex"":{""availableToBack"":[{""price"":7.0," _
                & """size"":286.85},{""price"":6.8,""size"":552.02},{""price"":6.6,""size"":25.81}],""availableToLay"":" _
                & "[{""price"":7.2,""size"":36.05},{""price"":7.4,""size"":312.79},{""price"":7.6,""size"":" _
                & "92.63}],""tradedVolume"":[]}},{""selectionId"":58805,""handicap"":0.0,""status"":" _
                & """ACTIVE"",""lastPriceTraded"":4.5,""totalMatched"":4390.5,""ex"":{""availableToBack"":" _
                & "[{""price"":4.5,""size"":209.65},{""price"":4.4,""size"":692.37},{""price"":4.3,""size"":429.69}]" _
                & ",""availableToLay"":[{""price"":4.6,""size"":279.02},{""price"":4.7,""size"":821.2}," _
                & "{""price"":4.8,""size"":928.88}],""tradedVolume"":[]}}]}],""id"":1}"

    ' PARSE FILE STRING
    Dim p As Object
    Set p = ParseJson(jsonStr)

    i = 5
    For Each element In p
        ' RESULT COLLECTION OF DICTIONARIES (N = 17)
        If element = "result" Then
            For Each e In p(element)
                For Each n In e
                    ' RUNNERS COLLECTION OF DICTIONARIES (N = 6)
                    If n = "runners" Then
                        For Each r In e(n)
                            For Each x In r
                                ' EX DICTIONARY OF COLLECTIONS (N = 9, 3 PER 3 RUNNERS)
                                If x = "ex" Then
                                    For Each s In r(x)
                                        num = 1
                                        For Each pr In r(x)(s)
                                            For Each dat In pr
                                                Sheets(1).Range("A" & i) = r("selectionId")
                                                Sheets(1).Range("B" & i) = r("handicap")
                                                Sheets(1).Range("C" & i) = r("status")
                                                Sheets(1).Range("D" & i) = r("lastPriceTraded")
                                                Sheets(1).Range("E" & i) = r("totalMatched")
                                                Sheets(1).Range("F" & i) = s
                                                Sheets(1).Range("G" & i) = num
                                                Sheets(1).Range("H" & i) = dat
                                                Sheets(1).Range("I" & i) = pr(dat)
                                                i = i + 1
                                            Next dat
                                            num = num + 1
                                         Next pr
                                    Next s
                                End If
                            Next x
                        Next r
                    End If
                Next n
            Next e
        End If
    Next element
End Sub
```

**Result** *(where 1.57, 7.2, and 4.6 are the first prices for availableToLay for each of three runners)*

```
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToBack 1   price   1.56
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToBack 1   size    1344.78
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToBack 2   price   1.55
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToBack 2   size    642.45
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToBack 3   price   1.54
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToBack 3   size    1034.4
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToLay  1   price   1.57
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToLay  1   size    303.34
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToLay  2   price   1.58
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToLay  2   size    2368.34
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToLay  3   price   1.59
48224   0   ACTIVE  1.57    37408.96    availableToLay  3   size    1220.99
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToBack 1   price   7
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToBack 1   size    286.85
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToBack 2   price   6.8
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToBack 2   size    552.02
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToBack 3   price   6.6
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToBack 3   size    25.81
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToLay  1   price   7.2
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToLay  1   size    36.05
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToLay  2   price   7.4
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToLay  2   size    312.79
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToLay  3   price   7.6
1141    0   ACTIVE  7       5863.62     availableToLay  3   size    92.63
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToBack 1   price   4.5
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToBack 1   size    209.65
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToBack 2   price   4.4
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToBack 2   size    692.37
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToBack 3   price   4.3
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToBack 3   size    429.69
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToLay  1   price   4.6
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToLay  1   size    279.02
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToLay  2   price   4.7
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToLay  2   size    821.2
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToLay  3   price   4.8
58805   0   ACTIVE  4.5     4390.5      availableToLay  3   size    928.88
```